How to execute functions at specific seconds every minute in python
I want to execute two functions every minute. After 1.5 seconds Dowork1() and Dowork2() also after 31 seconds execute Dowork2(). Following code is working but it is delaying and blocking other threads as this is continuous while loop. i have thought of using sleep two time but it will be messy and difficult to calculate exact time of sleep. Please let me know what is best way to do this.
dateTimeObj = datetime.now()
minute = dateTimeObj.minute
hour = dateTimeObj.hour
firstExecuteseconds = 1.5
secondExecuteseconds = 31.0
while True:
  if hour < datetime.now().hour:        
     hour = datetime.now().hour
     minute = datetime.now().minute - 1
  if minute < datetime.now().minute:
    isFirstExecuted = False
    isSecondExecuted = False
    if datetime.now().second > firstExecuteseconds and isFirstExecuted == False:
      DoWork1()
      DoWork2()
      isFirstExecuted = True
    if datetime.now().second > secondExecuteseconds and isSecondExecuted == False:
      DoWork2()
      isSecondExecuted = True
    if isFirstExecuted and isSecondExecuted:
      hour = datetime.now().hour
      minute = datetime.now().minute


What threads are you referring to?

This applications has 7 to 8 threads. if something is run in continuous while True: loop in one thread, other threads gets blocked or delayed.

Can you update your question to include a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? At first glance, it looks like you could solve the problem by adding a time.sleep to your loop; it doesn't need to run "continuously"; it can sleep until the next even needs to fire.

Also consider threading.Timer objects.

adding sleep is difficult as DoWork1() and DoWork2() execution time is different each time depending upon work given to them dynamically. So i don't know how much time to sleep.

Python threads don't work the way you would expect most of the time because of the GIL

If you want to run a function every one minute without blocking other threads, you can do:
import threading
import time

def my_task():
    print("Task executed at:", time.ctime())

def execute_task_every_minute():
    while True:
        my_task()
        time.sleep(60)  # Wait for 60 seconds before running again

# Create a thread to run the function
thread = threading.Thread(target=execute_task_every_minute)

# Start the thread
thread.start()

So you should make two threads for your functions and do sleeping in those threads which doesn't block your main thread.
You can also calculate the execution time of you operation and sleep the remaining time to be exact.

It will block your main thread somewhat because of the GIL

I think using the asyncio library makes sense since you are writing concurrent processes.
import asyncio

async def task1():
    await asyncio.sleep(1.5)
    print("task1()")

async def task2():
    await asyncio.sleep(31)
    print("task2()")

async def background_task():
    print("Long background task...")
    await asyncio.sleep(600)
    print("...done")

async def schedule_tasks():
    while True:
        start_time = asyncio.get_running_loop().time()
        task1_coroutine = asyncio.create_task(task1())
        task2_coroutine = asyncio.create_task(task2())
        elapsed_time = asyncio.get_running_loop().time() - start_time
        if elapsed_time < 60: 
            await asyncio.sleep(60 - elapsed_time)

async def main():
    asyncio.create_task(background_task())
    await schedule_tasks()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())

Does having multiple synchronous python programs interacting  make sense? You might want to learn about cron for starting programs on a schedule in Mac and Linux, or Windows Task Scheduler. Then you need to figure out how to do interprocess communication safely.

One way to do this is to separate the scheduler (your while loop) from the actual work being performed. Instead of performing the functions directly in the while loop, you can spawn new threads for each execution. This frees up the scheduler to continue checking the time and launch new threads with a good degree of precision and not have its timing impacted by waiting for tasks (your functions) to complete.
In a simplified example:
while True:
    if is_time_to_execute_task_1():
        task_thread = threading.Thread(target=DoWork1)
        task_thread.start()
    if is_time_to_execute_task_2():
        task_thread = threading.Thread(target=DoWork2)
        task_thread.start()
    time.sleep(0.01)  # or whatever resolution you need

